# How to resolve package dependencies after failed upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, 18.04

I tried to upgrade an Ubuntu machine from 16.04 to 18.04. Unfortunately the upgrade process was interrupted due to unrecoverable problems with package dependencies. I tried to fix this with `sudo apt install -f` but the problem can't apparently cant be resolved by apt. I get:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Abhängigkeiten werden korrigiert ... fehlgeschlagen.
Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 checkbox-converged : Hängt ab von: qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin ist aber nicht installierbar
 gdm3 : Hängt ab von: libgdm1 (= 3.20.1-1ubuntu2~ubuntu16.04.1) aber 3.28.0-0ubuntu1 ist installiert
        Hängt ab von: gir1.2-gdm-1.0 (= 3.20.1-1ubuntu2~ubuntu16.04.1) aber 3.28.0-0ubuntu1 ist installiert
 gnome-settings-daemon : Hängt ab von: gnome-settings-daemon-schemas (= 3.20.1-2ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04.1) aber 3.28.1-0ubuntu1 ist installiert
 libc-dev-bin : Hängt ab von: libc6 (< 2.24) aber 2.27-3ubuntu1 ist installiert
 libc6-dbg : Hängt ab von: libc6 (= 2.23-0ubuntu10) aber 2.27-3ubuntu1 ist installiert
 libc6-dev : Hängt ab von: libc6 (= 2.23-0ubuntu10) aber 2.27-3ubuntu1 ist installiert
 libqt5quick5 : Hängt ab von: libqt5core5a (>= 5.9.0~beta) aber 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 ist installiert
                Hängt ab von: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.9.0~beta) aber 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 ist installiert
                Hängt ab von: libqt5qml5 (>= 5.9.5) aber 5.5.1-2ubuntu6 ist installiert
                Hängt ab von: qtbase-abi-5-9-5
                Hängt ab von: qtdeclarative-abi-5-9-5
 libwayland-egl1-mesa : Hängt ab von: libegl1 ist aber nicht installiert
 qml-module-qtquick-window2 : Hängt ab von: libqt5core5a (>= 5.9.0~beta) aber 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 ist installiert
                              Hängt ab von: qtdeclarative-abi-5-9-5
 qml-module-qtwebkit : Hängt ab von: libqt5core5a (>= 5.9.0~beta) aber 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 ist installiert
                       Hängt ab von: qtdeclarative-abi-5-9-5
 qml-module-ubuntu-test : Hängt ab von: qml-module-ubuntu-components ist aber nicht installierbar
                          Hängt ab von: libubuntugestures5 ist aber nicht installierbar
 qml-module-ubuntu-web : Hängt ab von: qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin (>= 1.3) ist aber nicht installierbar oder
                                        qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin-gles (>= 1.3) ist aber nicht installierbar
 unity-webapps-qml : Hängt ab von: qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin ist aber nicht installierbar oder
                                    qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin-gles ist aber nicht installierbar
E: Fehler: Unterbrechungen durch pkgProblemResolver::Resolve hervorgerufen; dies könnte durch zurückgehaltene Pakete verursacht worden sein.
E: Abhängigkeiten konnten nicht korrigiert werden.
```

I tried to remove some packages manually to resolve the conflicts, but nothing worked. Can somebody give me a hint, for an more radical approach to resolve this.

Please don't suggest to do a complete new installation. We aren't in the Windows world here. I never did a complete new installation since I switched to Ubuntu in 2008, an I'm not in the mood to do it now...

Comment: Not a completely matter of removing, you'll need to upgrade those unremovable packages that are currently much older versions. You may need to aquire them manually. As far as never doing a fresh install since 2008, we'll at this point garbage in, garbage out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very easy solution to that problem: I installed `aptitude`. As my packet management was blocked by the above mentioned conflicts I had to do so, by manually grabbing the package and all its dependencies from here: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=aptitude

You can simply install them, by putting them all in a custom folder an execute:

```
dpkg -i *.deb
```

After this was done, I could solve the conflicts by:

```
sudo aptitude upgrade
```

Holly cow! Great experience!